# Как открыть несколько коммитов git рядом в Nodepad++ ?

Tags: git

Чтобы рядом были открыты версии new и old; и полноценно можно было просматривать old, копировать из нее и вставлять в new.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под new и old?

Comment: Одна старая рабочая версия веб-страницы, к примеру, но без анимации, к примеру. И новая экспериментальная где я настраиваю эту анимацию; в ней я пишу новое, копируя что-то из старой стабильной версии.

Comment: То есть, из разных веток, если я правильно понял. Если так, то поправте вопрос.